# TeamCity get version of newly created package

Tags: c#, .net-core, continuous-integration, nuget, teamcity

I am using teamcity to build a netstandard2.0 library.
I have a dotnet pack build step and I output the result to a specific location.

```
/TCOutput/ClassLib/ClassLib.1.0.0.nupkg
/TCOutput/ClassLib/ClassLib.1.2.0.nupkg
/TCOutput/ClassLib/ClassLib.1.3.0.nupkg
/TCOutput/ClassLib/ClassLib.1.4.0.nupkg
```

Next I want to publish the nuget to our corporate nuget server. I am trying to create a nuget publish step and in the Packages section I specify `%env.TEAMCITY_PACKAGES_OUTPUT%\%system.teamcity.projectName%\???.nupkg` which is the path but I dont know how to get the current version in order to point Teamcity to get the correct nupkg file

How can I get the newly created nupkg version

Comment: What TC variable do you use when deciding the name of the `nupkg` file in the first place?

Comment: I dont use any variable. I suppose dotnet pack creates the file based on the package version specified in the csproj file

Comment: What build number shows in TeamCity when the build has finished i.e. does it match your nuget package versions?

Comment: @EvolveSoftwareLtd no it does not match. If I find a way to get the package version using dotnet cli it would be nice. I can then pass the version to a TC variable I. created.

Comment: Use the "Version suffix" property of Dotnet pack command and add your build version to it, in the next step while publishing you can use the same build number to identify newly created package.

Comment: I increase version on VS2019 so I cannot do it on dotnet pack. Unless there is a way to retrieve the package version using the dotnet cli